# .NET webform Hide a HTML td column in backend server (Update Panel, Content Template)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an instance, it shows a listView.

the listview is in the update panel, it needs to response to each data source binding and show/hide a column in the listView table by checking a Session.

I cannot simply add

```
<% if((int)Session["v1"] ==1) { %> <td>Hi</td> <%}%>
```

as the exception throw saying that the update panel cannot update when <% %> exists.

(but it works for the control outside of the update panel)

I think I can do it by javascript but I just want to make sure if there is a smarter way to do in the backend.

```
class='<%# HiddenClass %>'
```

and changing this parameter during onload (change HiddenClass to empty string if the column should show.

It works for the item's column (in the **ItemTemplate**) but it doesn't work for the item's header column **LayoutTemplate** (i think it is because data source binding only re-rendered the fields in the **ItemTemplate** and not included **LayoutTemplate**.

currently, I was able to hide it to set the  runat="server" Visible to false if for each data source binding of the listview. But it looks very complicated when I need to hide more columns (need to create more ID and asp.net cannot set visible of fields by class).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `<td></td>` with a `PlaceHolder` and set it's Visibility property from code behind.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <td>Hi</td>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

And then in code behind

```
if ((int)Session["v1"] == 1)
{
    PlaceHolder1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: hi, doing this is the same as i set an ID and runat="server" to the <td> ... both of them will throw exception with layout template isn't loaded ( when there is no records in the datasource, ListView will load its empty template instead of the LayoutTemplate and thus whatever the place holder or <td runat=server> will also throw exception during databinding

Comment: i just found that the exception can be avoided, it is my mistake. but the problem is even through using the place holder, i still need to create two place holder ( as there is two html td i required to hide and their positon is not stick together.